# Y a-t-il un déclin du sens d'excès et/ou péjoratif du verbe « louanger » ?

Tags: sens, usage, synonymes

> Le parcours de cette femme [Mme Ardern] en politique est exemplaire et inspirant à
> bien des égards. Lui dire merci pour sa candeur, son authenticité, sa
> transparence, sa lucidité, son humanité à l’égard de sa noble sortie
> de scène est fort à propos. Mais on devrait aussi la **louanger** et
> surtout l’ériger en modèle au regard de sa façon très démocratique
> d’avoir exercé le pouvoir. (Jean-Pierre Charbonneau ds. [Lapresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/opinions/2023-01-27/legault-devrait-s-inspirer-de-jacinda-ardern.php), je souligne)

[TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/louanger) : [Correspond à [louer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/louer)(1); souvent dans un contexte péjoratif, ironique] Louer (quelqu'un ou quelque chose) généralement avec excès, sans discernement.
[Ac.9](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9L1243) : Couvrir de [louanges](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9L1242), d’éloges ; louer avec excès.
[Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/louanger) : Couvrir de louanges. *Louanger le travail, l'effort de quelqu'un.*

Cette présentation passe de *souvent négatif*, *généralement avec excès* à *louer avec excès* comme proposition distincte à aucune mention d'excès mais simplement *couvrir* (qui implique une certaine densité ou grande quantité).

- Y a-t-il un déclin du sens d'excès et/ou péjoratif du verbe *louanger*
  généralement ou régionalement (Québec) ?
- Tend-on à substituer de plus en plus *louanger* à *louer* ?
- Dans le texte cité, où il n'y a aucune connotation péjorative,
  l'emploi du verbe *louer* aurait-il créé un malencontreux
  sous-entendu en trompe-l’œil du type « prendre à son service » etc.
  ([louer](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/louer/1)) et pense-t-on que c'est ce qui justifiait l'emploi de
  *louanger* ici ?

Answer (score 2):

En tant que francophone habitant en France, j'entends très peu *louanger*.

J'en tire que l'auteur de cette citation, qui est québécois, applique la règle qui veut que le Québec utilise davantage de mots et d'expressions littéraires (comme le qualifie le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/louanger/47860)) ou vieillies, en plus du vocabulaire régional, que la francophonie dans son ensemble.

En effet, rien n'interdit l'usage de *louer* dans cet extrait, car pour moi il n'y a pas confusion de sens. Et le choix de *louanger* n'est visiblement pas motivé par l'ironie. C'est donc le verbe qui est venu naturellement à cette personne.

> Tend-on à substituer de plus en plus louanger à louer ?

À moins que cette question se focalise sur le cas du Québec, ce serait plutôt l'inverse.